# How to use DbContext in T4 template?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, t4

I want to generate some code with a T4 Template using EntityFramework. I created a T4 Template in the same Assembly as my currently working EF6 DbContext:

```
<#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="true" debug="True" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetPath)" #>
<#@ import namespace="Conwell.Administration.Data.Entities" #>

<#
    using (var db = new KassenautomatEntities())
    {
#>
//Hello World
<#
    }
#>
```

When I run it, I get the following execption:

> Running transformation: System.InvalidOperationException:
>
> The 'Instance' member of the Entity Framework provider type
>   'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices,
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' did not return an object that
>   inherits from 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices'.
>   Entity Framework providers must inherit from this class and the
>   'Instance' member must return the singleton instance of the provider.
>   This may be because the provider does not support Entity Framework 6
>   or later; see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more
>   information.

The same context works fine outside of T4. What I am missing?

Comment: I suppose that you will have to make a `KassenautomatEntities` definition in a separate assembly. Then reference to this assembly can be used in T4.

Comment: I have just started getting this error after upgrading from VS2015 to VS2017. If I run the same script in VS2015 it works, so that is how I have been getting by but Christian did you ever discover the fix for this? And to @AlexanderPetrov my DbContext class is in a separate assembly, here I have proven that the template is complete because I am using it in VS2015, so what has changed in the context that the code is generated in VS2017

Comment: I am afraid to say, I have used plain ado.net @ChrisSchaller

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same error, and the way to get it working was:

1. Ensure to reference both EntityFramework, and your provider DLLs on
   Your T4 template; This is enough to get rid of this error.

> ```
> <#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)\EntityFramework.dll" #>
> <#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" #>
> ```

2. Config files aren't read since T4 runs in a different context; hence you'll need to create a DbContext constructor accepting a connection string; then you pass it while creating the context in T4

Comment: I came across this post during my struggle to get the Entity Framework to work with Oracle from a T4 template. Still struggling with the initial error in this post. This seems to work OK for MSSQL but not for Oracle. Any suggestions you could give me?

Comment: @PaulSinnema This error is about a missing reference, did you reference oracle dll? i.e. Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, also ensure to reference all dlls needed.