# T4 templates failing because they try to load assemblies from visual studio common directory

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, t4, assembly-loading

We've got a project that uses the Entity Framework to CRUD data to/from the database.

I'm now trying to write a T4 template that uses the EF access to generate testdata in code form like `var users = new List<User>{ new User {...}, new User {...} };`.

When I try to access the functions that retrieve data from the DB, I get an error saying that the Entity Framework Provider didn't return an object that inherits from System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.

Ok, forget about the error for a moment: My guess is that the assembly that takes care of the Entity Framework Access normally loaded from the `bin\debug\` directory now is being loaded from the Visual Studio Working Directory which is somewhere in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\` directory. This causes different assemblies to be found. I don't want to use the absolute paths for all needed assemblies, for that would cause problems for my colleagues which possibly have a different configuration on their PC's.

Is it possible to direct the template to be run from the $(SolutionDir)?

**EDIT**

I think I'm a step further: The script below now asks for an entry in the App.config for the connection string, which in turn is not in the working directory of Visual Studio.

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="false" language="C#" compileOptions="-P $(SolutionDir)Wur.Epros.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="System" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Configuration" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data.Common" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data.Entity" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.IO.Compression" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Runtime.Serialization" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Security" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.ServiceModel" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Transactions" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.CSharp" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)packages\CuttingEdge.Conditions.1.2.0.0\lib\NET35\CuttingEdge.Conditions.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)packages\Castle.Core.4.3.1\lib\net45\Castle.Core.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)packages\NLog.4.5.11\lib\net45\NLog.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)packages\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.12.2.1100\lib\net40\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)packages\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.12.2.20190115\lib\net45\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)packages\structuremap.2.6.3\lib\StructureMap.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)Wur.Epros.Core\bin\debug\Wur.Epros.Core.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)Wur.Epros.Core.Tests\bin\debug\Wur.Epros.Core.Tests.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="Wur.Epros.Core.Domain" #>
<#@ import namespace="Wur.Epros.Core.Infrastructure" #>
<#@ import namespace="Wur.Epros.Core.Tests.Mock" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Entity" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="StructureMap" #>
<#@ import namespace="Wur.Epros.Core.Infrastructure.StructureMap" #>
<#@ import namespace="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>


// Test

<#
    try
    {
        ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
            {
            x.AddRegistry<CoreRegistry>();
            x.Scan(scan =>
                {
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                scan.LookForRegistries();
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                });
            });

        Wur.Epros.Core.Infrastructure.Environment.InitEnvironment();

        DataClass.GenerateData<EPROS_SETUP>(DataClass.GetData<EPROS_SETUP>());
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
#>
/* <#=          ex.Message #>
   <#=          ex.InnerException == null ? "null" : ex.InnerException.Message #>  */


<#
    }
#>
```

**EDIT 2**

Another step closer to solving this but still not there. I've added the following code to initialize the script above (also edited a bit).

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Wur.Epros.Core.Infrastructure
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Environment variables
    /// </summary>
    public static class Environment
    {
        public static void InitEnvironment()
        {
            DbConfiguration conf = new MyConf();
            DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(conf);
        }
    }

    public class MyConf : DbConfiguration
    {
        public MyConf()
        {
            SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory("v13.0"));
            SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlClient", System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance);
            SetProviderServices("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client", Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices.Instance);
        }
    }
}
```

I now get the following error:

`[A]Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection cannot be cast to [B]Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection. Type A originates from 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' in the context 'Default' at location 'c:\program files (x86)\oracle developer tools for vs2017\odp.net\managed\common\oracle.manageddataaccess.dll'. Type B originates from 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' in the context 'LoadFrom' at location 'C:\Users\<userId>\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\15K0NR5V.AGY\O2O039L7.GXW\137c2a2f\00141e2f_86d5d201\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll'.`

It tries to load the assembly from 2 different locations. I guess the second location is where the T4 process stores assemblies temporarily.

Comment: Can't get passed the configuration problem. It searches for the App.config in de devenv working directory. Can't add it dynamically to the in-memory configuration (readonly). Can add it to the Entity Framework DBContext but still searches the App.config. I guess the best solution would be to be able to alter the working directory the TextTemplatingFileGenerator is running in.

Comment: Came across this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103322/how-to-use-dbcontext-in-t4-template. Still not working

Comment: Forgot to mention. In the above solution the connectionstring for the EF is solved using 'var context = new EprosEntities("<my connection string>");' That seems to work.

Comment: Removed my remark. I would like an answer for this problem. Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: EF & Oracle? If you have any choice in the matter, go a different way. Use IDataReaders for Selects and Commands for everything else. It may be basic but its tried and tested.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to go a different way too. I would choose DataObjects.Net b.t.w. But the preferred technology is to be Microsoft I'm afraid. The Oracle DB is legacy which will be replaced in the future some time.

Comment: I've had this kind of trouble before using T4. It is such a powerful tool but has it's drawbacks. It should be possible however because the EF uses DB connections too for investigating DB's.

Answer (score 0):

I stopped looking using T4 for this problem and solved it using a console application that generates the data into a file. The files are loaded into the Mock objects.